# What is this cotton-like stuff growing on my pizza sauce?

Tags: food-safety, sauce, mold

The sauce was to expire in Nov 2013. I kept it in the fridge all the time. The thing that grew on it was white in color (just like cotton). There was a greenish center. The overall "ball" was about 1 cm in diameter, and they were all over in the bottle.

I don't have a picture of it, because I had to throw it out. I don't know what it was, or how it started growing.

What was it? Why was it there?

Comment: [FUNGUS](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/FactSheets/Molds_On_Food/)

Comment: Note that the expiration date applies only to an *unopened* jar. Once open, you can't count on more than a few days before it starts getting fuzzy.

Answer (score 12):

It's mould. You've probably seen it growing on bread. Refrigeration slows it down, but eventually it'll grow.

You didn't say when you bought it and opened it. Perhaps your fridge is not set cold enough?

Comment: In terms of timeline, I bought it on day 0, opened on day 3, and refrigerated it ASAP. Then the second time, I opened it on day 6-ish, and found some of the mold. I'm just confused how can mold grow on a new food product in the fridge.

Comment: So what is the temperature of your fridge? Are you sure the door is still sealed correctly and it's in working order? I ask this as a person who once had a fridge with a slightly wonky door and this made everything spoil really quickly.

Comment: I don't know about the temperature. But it is pretty cool. The door is fine though.

Comment: @KaranGoel Your fridge should be in the 2-4C range, not just cool, but close to freezing.

Comment: To answer the question how anything could have grown in there -- did you dip anything into the container that might've been contaminated?  A spoon that's also touched other stuff can be enough to add mold or other contaminents.

Comment: Fungus spores are floating around in the air. It only takes one spore to land in your sauce while it's open. They will grow at fridge temperature.

Comment: @None Fungus can grow even on refrigerated food if you don't handle it safely. For e.g. keeping it out of the fridge for longer periods or using wet or unclean spoon or touching food without washing your hands.

Answer (score 5):

Like @sarino and @megasaur mentioned already, it is mold and you did the right thing by throwing it away. This link explains pretty well why mold grows on the food: http://wanttoknowit.com/why-does-mold-grow-on-food/

Also, the reason that food stays good in these unopened bottles in normal temperatures is that the food is vacuum sealed, so it doesn't come into contact with air or outside moisture. Once its opened, it is highly recommended to go into the fridge straight away, like you did.